# How to open XML with XSL file in Applet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, japplet, jaxm

I have XML and XSL file and I have also declared XSL in XML file. So I want to open XML file in Java `JApplet`. So If possible any component is there in Java?

```
<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="emp.xsl"?>
..
```

Comment: Do you merely wish to load the XML, or to load it and transform it according to the XSL?  *"Please do the needful."*  I generally ***avoid*** the needful/needy & go on to help other people.  Best to leave such noise out of questions.

Comment: See also [*Java & XSLT*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596001438.do).